# Get Output parameter and Dataset from Stored Procedure using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I'm trying to call the stored procedure attached below using Entity Framework 4.1 to cover 2 possible scenarios:

- exec TEST_SP_OUTPUT 1
  Should return a dataset from ACTIONTYPE table and @Success = 1
- exec TEST_SP_OUTPUT 0
  No dataset returned and @Success = 0

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_SP_OUTPUT]
  (
    @Id int, 
    @Success int OUTPUT
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF (@Id = 1)
    BEGIN
      SELECT ActionName, ActionType FROM ACTIONTYPE   
      SET @Success = 1;
    END
  ELSE
      SET @Success = 0;
  END
  ```

The question is: **can I handle both executions using a single Complex Type within the Entity Framework model?**
Bear in mind that the scenario "exec TEST_SP_OUTPUT 0" is not returning any dataset or columns.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I a possible solution may be setting dummy results for the second scenario:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_SP_OUTPUT]
    (
      @Id int, 
      @Success int OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@Id = 1)
      BEGIN
        SELECT ActionName, ActionType FROM ACTIONTYPE   
        SET @Success = 1;
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN            
        SELECT '' as ActionName, '' as ActionType
        SET @Success = 0;
      END
    END
```

Cheers.

Juan.